# PFRelation property on model subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is it possible to use `PFRelation` as a property on model?

I have a simple class like this:

```
@interface Grocery : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) PFRelation* apples;

@end

@implementation Grocery

@dynamic apples;

@end
```

`Grocery.apples` even returns something sane but there is no way to fetch objects using returned `relation` because `relation.query` does not apparently reference right stuff.

I assume that dynamic PFRelation does not have enough information to resolve Parse class for relation.

So far the only way to fix this was to make a subclass of PFRelation in such fashion:

```
@interface AppleRelation : PFRelation
@property (strong) Grocery* parentObject;
@end

@implementation AppleRelation

- (NSString*)targetClass {
    return [Apple parseClassName];
}

- (PFQuery*)query {
    PFQuery* query = [super query];

    // Scope to parent
    [query whereKey:@"parent" equalTo:self.parentObject];

    return query;
}

@end
```

I wonder if I missed some `parseClassForRelation:` somewhere that would allow automatic relations being generated or is it simply a bug in Parse SDK?